# Vue.js screen size responsiveness

Tags: javascript, vue.js, responsive-design

[image]

I gave margin-left to my component because my side-bar was blocking "Roles" and table as well.

How can I move my table to right when screen is less than 992? I want it to be responsive to all screen sizes and I am using Bootstrap vue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can use a media query that will run if the screen is 992px or less with

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px){
  .my-table{
    // css 
 }
}
```

but if you are using bootstrap-vue you can also pass the 'responsive' prop.

```
 <b-table responsive hover striped :items="items" class="position-relative"></b-table>
```

Comment: I used margin-left and my table is stable, I want my table to move right when screen size is equal or less than 992. I tried a lot of javascript codes none of them helped me.

Comment: Add the media query example in your css section of the component. Replace '.my-table' with the class you put on b-table to do our original margin-left. then just do a 'margin-right'. also note that when using the responsive prop you should include the 'position-relative' or you may get weird results with extra space on small screens. so it would look like this class="myClassName position-relative"

Comment: I got that I should play with max-width and min-width, thanks dude!